# How to fetch a particular field from HTTPResponse POST method in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

Can someone please help me out with the approach to display contractID in html page when I could see the response in Network Tab of browser as : http:localhost:8080/api -> {contractId: 70, contractName: "HealthPlan2",contractServiceList
:....}.
I am confused since I do not have explicit get method from Web API to fetch this data but I can see this response in my browser. 
Currently I am saving into the API using http.post(), I am totally unaware of this functionality of Angular. Someone please explain how it;s internally working and how can I fetch an auto-generated ID which is not the part of my post method. Any suggestion on Interceptor would be good.

In app.component.ts

```
createForm(data: any): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      contractId: [data ? data.contractId : ''],
      contractName: [data ? data.contractName : '', Validators.required],
      contractServiceList: this.formBuilder.array(
             this.createContractService(data ? data.contractServiceList : null),this.arrayValidator()
              )
      });
  }
ngOnInit() {
     {
    this.addForm = this.createForm(null);
    //  this.addForm.get('contractName').valueChanges.subscribe(changes => { console.log(changes) } )
   // this.addForm.valueChanges.subscribe(changes => { console.log( '*', changes) } )
    }
  }
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.successMessage = '';
    this.errorMessage = '';
    console.log(this.addForm.value);
    if (this.addForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }
        this.getByName;
    this.contractService.saveContract(this.addForm.value)
      .subscribe( data => {
        this.successMessage = 'Contract created successfully';
      });
  }
```

In app.component.html

```
 <table>
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="contractId" ng-model="contractId" style="display: none;"/>
  </td>
   <td>
   <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="contractName">Contract Name:</label>
      <input formControlName="contractName" placeholder="Contract Name" class="form-control" name="contractName" id="contractName">
   <!--  <div *ngIf="submitted && f.contractName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.contractName.errors.required">Contract Name is required</div>
                        </div> -->
                    </div>
   </td>
   <td>
 <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
     <h4 style="margin-left:100px;">Penalty Conditions</h4>
    </div>
</td>  
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div formArrayName="contractServiceList">
<div *ngFor="let items of contractList.controls; let i=index" 
            [formGroupName]="i">
<table>
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
<tr> 
<td>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="serviceId">Category Of Services:</label>
      <select id ="serviceId" [(ngModel)]="serviceId" formControlName="serviceId" name="serviceId" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Emergency Room</option>
    <option value="2">OP Radiology</option>
</select>
      </div>
    </td>
<td>
 <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="penaltyApplies">Penalty Applies:</label>
       <select id ="penaltyApplies" formControlName="penaltyApplies" name="penaltyApplies" class="form-control">
    <option>Y</option>
    <option>N</option>
</select>
```

.....

In service.ts

```
saveContract(contract: Contract) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, contract).pipe(map(res => res.json));
  }
```

Comment: You need not convert your response to `json`, you already get `json` data by default which is converted by angular6 `HttpClient`. So in your case you really do not need `map` also because you just want to return back to `component`. `return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, contract);`

Comment: @AmitChigadani: Yes will remove that. But my problem is how do I fetch auto-generated ID from server which I can see in Networks tab in browser. Hope u understand the question.

Comment: What does it print if you log data inside subscribe?

Comment: @Amit Chigadani: It prints contractName and the ServiceList{....}. Since all these fields are in html and Iam doing a form submit. Also when I open Network tab in my browser I could see the call going to server, there I find contractId value also. I have to fetch that.

Comment: That id should also be a part of response right? Then why it is not printing id when you can see it on network tab? What does it print for data.id?

Comment: yes exactly it would be part of response but Iam printing this.form.value, how to get that response and extract contractId from it is my question

Comment: By simply doing data.contractId? And you may save it and then display on view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179700/discussion-between-meenal-and-amit-chigadani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the chat section it was clear that OP is using `Http`.
Instead you can use `HttpClient` for angular 4 and above, which comes from `@angular/common/http`

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
export class ContractService { 
     constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } 
     ......
}
```

You may also have to import `HttpClientModule` in app  module.

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
   HttpClientModule
 ],
```

And also you need not explicitly convert your resp to `json` with this, you already get `json` data by default which is converted by new angular `HttpClient`. So in your case you really do not need map also because you just want to return back to `component`

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class ContractService { 
     constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } 

     saveContract(contract: Contract) {
        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, contract).pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError));
     }
}
```

Comment: How can we add .catch(this.handleError) if we are not converting to json. Is there directly we can catch exceptions of this saveContract() method. Please guide!

Comment: You may use catchError to handle exceptions. I will modify it in a while wait.. I am typing from phone

Comment: Yeah np. Please modify the saveContract method in order to handle direct HTTP Exceptions.

Comment: I have added err => { 
this.errorMessage = err; 
console.log(err); 
});  in component.ts but I am getting Error Message as [Object: object] in UI
}

Comment: What does `console.log(err)` print?

Comment: It prints [Object: object].

Comment: [object Object]

Comment: Check if this works for you. Do `{{errorMessage | json}}` in your view

Comment: Now I am getting Error! { "headers": { "normalizedNames": {}, "lazyUpdate": null, "headers": {} }, "status": 0, "statusText": "Unknown Error", "url": null, "ok": false, "name": "HttpErrorResponse", "message": "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error", "error": { "isTrusted": true } }. I need only "message" part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Response of Post method returned as an observable in your saveContract function and also mapped to Json correctly. so you can subscribe to retrieve the fields you want.

inside your `onSubmit()` function:

```
 this.contractService.saveContract(this.addForm.value)
      .subscribe( (data:any) => {

       //here you can access contractID:
       this.contractIdShownInUI = data.contractID;  

       this.successMessage = 'Contract created successfully';
      });
```

Comment: But Iam not saving contractID in this.addForm.value, it's auto-generated in DB and I could see that when Angular makes a call to server. Also note I donot have any get method in server for this.

Comment: if `contractID` is generated on the server and sent back to you on the post method's response that code shows how to retrieve it. if its not let me know

Comment: data.contractID; is giving error Property 'contractID' does not exist on type 'Response. any'

Comment: try this: 
`.subscribe( data:any => { 
console.log(data.contractId); 
this.successMessage = 'Contract created successfully'; 
});`

Comment: getting all values as 'undefined' when I did  this.contractService.saveContract(this.addForm.value)
      .subscribe((data : any) => {
        console.log(data.contractID);
        console.log(data.contractName);
        this.successMessage = 'Contract created successfully';
      });

Comment: @Meenal so what is your response?

Comment: @Antoniossss: just did this.form.value and I got all the values saving through html, don't know how to check response.

Comment: And if I do console.log(data), getting ƒ () {
        if (typeof this._body === 'string') {
            return JSON.parse(this._body);
        }
        if (this._body instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
            return JSON.parse(this.text());
  …

Comment: @Meenal `console.log(data)`? You clearly have no clue what you are doing here.